# Java Boolean to test for unique integers

Tags: java, boolean, try-catch

I'm trying to write a simple java code that asks the user to input three UNIQUE integers and then the system will check to see if they are in fact three different integers, and if two are the same then the program will start the method over again.  I have the user input the integers but the `boolean` does not check for unique integers and instead simply ends the program. The area in question is the `public static boolean`.

The errors I am getting are, on line 66:

> Syntax error on boolean, delete this token

and, on line 68:

> getNumbers cannot be resolved to a variable

```
import java.util.Scanner;                     //PRE-WRITTEN CODE FROM SCANNER CLASS

public class NumbersPetrantoni {

    public static int num1;
    public static int num2;
    public static int num3;
    public static boolean verifyDiff;

    public static void main(String args[]) {     // MAIN METHOD USED TO CALL OTHER METHODS
        getNumbers();                               // USER INPUTS THREE UNIQUE NUMBERS TO BE CALCULATED
        boolean verifyDiff;                         // COMPUTER VERIFIES THAT THREE UNIQUE INTEGERS EXIST
    }             // END OF MAIN METHOD

    public static void getNumbers() {
        boolean done = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (done != true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Let's do some basic math!");
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter three unique integers: ");
                System.out.print("\nNumber 1: ");
                num1 = input.nextInt();                  // METHOD USED TO INPUT FIRST INTEGER
                System.out.print("Number 2: ");
                num2 = input.nextInt();                  // "" SECOND INTEGER
                System.out.print("Last but not least, Number 3: ");
                num3 = input.nextInt();                  // "" THIRD INTEGER 
                done = true;
            } catch(Exception message) {
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\nDo you know what an integerer is?"); 
                System.out.println("The program threw a " + message + " message at me, NOT a real integer.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex){};         
                System.out.println("\nREBOOTING...\n");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex){};
            }                // END - CATCH SECTION 
        }                    // END - WHILE LOOP        
    }       // END - GET NUMBERS METHOD

    public static boolean verifyDiff(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        boolean allDiff = false;
        if(num1 != num2 && num1 != num3 && num2 != num3)                           
            allDiff = true;                  
        return allDiff;
        if(boolean allDiff = false)
            System.out.println("Thee UNIQUE integers, please.");
        getNumbers;
    }                                     // END - VERIFY DIFF METHOD
}       // END - NumbersPetrantoni CLASS
```

Comment: Do you see line numbers here? In the future, indicate which line  the error is happening on more clearly.

Comment: You should really restructure that. On the other hand, just by saying: `return ((num1 != num2) && (num2 != num3))` is enough.

Comment: `if(boolean allDiff = false)` should be `if (!allDiff)`, among many other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
boolean verifyDiff;   // COMPUTER VERIFIES THAT THREE UNIQUE INTEGERS EXIST
```

you want:

```
verifyDiff(num1, num2, num3);
```

inside your `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

You never verify that your values aren't equal, you just create a variable called `verifyDiff`. And this recursion could easily be avoided. Use:

```
do{
    getNumbers();
}while(verifyDiff(num1 , num2 , num3));
```

and remove the `getNumbers()` from the end of `verifyDiff()`. And btw. your recursion wouldn't work anyways, since you only call `getNumbers()` from `verifyDiff()`, but not the other way. And you should **always** check if you're using variables or methods!!!